# Which is the most correct pattern for using Stack.Pop?

Tags: c#, stack

There at least 2 patterns of using `Stack.Pop`

1. ```
   private Stack<T> availableResources;
   ...
   if (availableResources.Count > 0) 
   {
     resource = availableResources.Pop();
     ...
   }
   ```
2. ```
   private Stack<T> availableResources;
   ...
   try 
   {
     resource = availableResources.Pop();
     ...
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException e)
   {
     ...
   }
   ```

I'd like to ask people, which of 2 is preferable? If possible, argument your answer.

Comment: Save your exceptions for exceptional cases you don't know how to handle. Patterns 2 is good for wrapping a method that can fail for various non-related or unknown reasons (`DownloadRemoteFile(url)`). Or for python.

Answer (score 17):

Program defensively and use option 1.

Since the `Stack` class provides the ability to check whether it contains anything before trying to `Pop` a value from it, you should do the check and avoid using the exception for flow control.

If you want to avoid doing the `if` check throughout your application, you could create a `TryPop` extension.

```
public static class StackExtensions
{
    public static bool TryPop<T>(this Stack<T> stack, out T value)
    {
        if (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            value = stack.Pop();
            return true;
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It could be used in the following way:

```
T resource;
if (availableResources.TryPop(out resource)) 
{
    // use `resource` for something
}
```

*It's worth noting that this approach is only suitable if the `Stack` is not accessed concurrently!* - If it is, and you are using .NET 4.0 onwards then you should use [ConcurrentStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331.aspx), otherwise create your own concurrent stack which encapsulates a `Stack` and manages access to it with locks.

Comment: Be careful when implementing your own concurrent stack. For example, checking `Count` before `Pop()` is not thread-safe, even if each of those methods is. You would need a thread-safe `TryPop()` and no `Pop()`, like .Net 4.0 `ConcurrentStack` does.

Answer (score 1):

First we should check, is there concurrent access to stack, or not. 
If it is, the first pattern doesn't handle an exception ('cause between the check and popping itself there can be an additional popping from the other thread), so consider using either ConcurrentStack<> or double-checking lock. 
Without them, in concurrent case, the second pattern is definitely better.

Comment: Stack.Pop might still destroy internal data structures when used concurrently without locks which makes Stack behave unpredictable. ConcurrentStack or locks.